# Why does Polymer 3.0 require the flat flag?

Tags: polymer

Not previously familiar with the flat flag, why is it required for a Polymer 3.0 project?

Have searched the web for clues but only found brief hints that the flat flag should be avoided.

Comment: As I understand it, the flat flag prevents npm from including multiple definitions of the same custom element. Multiple class of the same custom element would confuse (and break?) the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

... This below from polymer-project's blog, why ?

**[Bower ➙ npm](https://www.polymer-project.org/blog/2017-08-22-npm-modules)**
Like HTML Imports, Bower has been with us for a long time. Bower's flat dependency tree is ideal for front-end projects. But Bower has never been as widely adopted as npm, and while it's still maintained, it's no longer being actively developed.

Moving to npm will make Polymer packages seamlessly available to the millions of npm users, and allow Polymer packages to easily use other packages from the massive npm ecosystem.

This has been a long requested feature, but we've been waiting until we had good solutions for supporting flat installs of modules and keeping Bower and npm packages in sync.

The Yarn npm client provides support for flat installs, which solves our #1 issue with npm.

After considering a number of approaches to keeping Bower and npm packages in sync, we concluded that maintaining parallel versions was impractical. So we're making a clean break at 3.x and moving to npm exclusively.

Comment: According to messages posted on the Polymer Slack channel, they are trying to find a better path forward, that doesn't involve the --flat flag.


As I understand it, when using a build tool, multiple versions of the same custom element can be prevented without the need for the --flat flag.